# Angular switching between components and pass a value as well

Tags: angular, components, parent-child

I have a navigation page that has two options (let's say finance and shipping) to go to next page which opens up either of the two main components. And each component has a list of orderId's which when clicked gives details about either finance or shipping. Now, when I am on one of the main pages I need to be able to switch to the other with a click of a button without using routing. I also need to pass the orderId that is currently selected so that when the other component opens the orderId is also selected from the list and it opens the child component for details. Which approach would be most appropriate for this? Sorry for the limited information and no code. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: "Now, when I am on one of the main pages I need to be able to switch to the other with a click of a button without using routing" - why without using routing..?

Comment: I was actually able to use routing to go to the next main page and I used a behavior subject to observe the orderId that I needed to pass. Thank you for your comment, I was able to use the orderId to open the child component that I needed to open. Turned out it was simpler than I thought.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.